# Docusign - Create envelope from PDF form

Tags: docusignapi

We have a document, a PDF Form, and we have labelled one of the fields in the PDF form as “prescriber_signature” where we want to place a signature placeholder.

We are sending a document to create the envelope and here is my request body. Attached is the document that we are sending as part of this multipart request.

We are not successful so far in getting the signature placeholder placed per the label name “prescriber_signature”. Can you look into the xml and suggest us what needs to be done please?

XML Body:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <emailSubject>DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document</emailSubject>
   <status>sent</status>
   <documents>
      <document>
         <documentId>1</documentId>
         <name>Samplefileflattenedfalse.pdf</name>
      </document>
   </documents>
   <recipients>
      <signers>
         <signer>
            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
            <clientUserId>1234</clientUserId>
            <email>prasanna112@gmail.com</email>
            <name>POC Prescriber Name</name>
            <tabs>
               <signHereTabs>
                  <signHere>
                     **
                     <anchorString>prescriber_signature</anchorString>
                     **
                     <anchorXOffset>1</anchorXOffset>
                     <anchorYOffset>0</anchorYOffset>
                     <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                     <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
                  </signHere>
               </signHereTabs>
            </tabs>
         </signer>
      </signers>
   </recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're combining to unique DocuSign features here.  The first feature is the ability to transform PDF form fields into DocuSign fields - such as signature fields, data fields, etc.

The second feature, which is completely separate, is the Anchor Tagging feature (also called AutoPlace).  With this feature you can tell DocuSign to place any types of fields at certain locations in your documents.  Those locations are based on the actual document content itself (i.e. what the viewer sees), not the PDF form field names.

---

From what I can tell I think you are trying to use the first feature listed above (PDF Form fields transformed into DocuSign fields).  As such, please see the following page from the API Guide which explains the transform rules:

[DocuSign API Guide - Document Parameters](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm)

The following information can be found through this page:

```
When extrapolating Adobe text fields, the following Adobe names correspond to DocuSign names:

Adobe name contains DocuSignSignHere or eSignSignHere = DocuSign Signature

Adobe name contains DocuSignSignHereOptional or eSignSignHereOptional = DocuSign Optional Signature

Adobe name contains DocuSignInitialHere or eSignInitialHere = DocuSign Initials

Adobe name contains DocuSignInitialHereOptional or eSignInitialHereOptional = DocuSign Optional Initials

Adobe name contains DocuSignEnvelopeID or eSignEnvelopeID = DocuSign EnvelopeID

Adobe name contains DocuSignCompany or eSignCompany = DocuSign Company

*Adobe name contains DocuSignDateSigned or eSignDateSigned = DocuSign DateSigned

Adobe name contains DocuSignTitleor eSignTitle = DocuSign Title

Adobe name contains DocuSignFullNameor eSignFullName = DocuSign FullName

Adobe name contains DocuSignSignerAttachmentOptional or eSignSignerAttachmentOptional = DocuSign Optional Attachment

Any other name will default to a DocuSign data (text) field
```